# Dúvida no While com duas condições

Tags: c

Eu estou com um exercício pra fazer e estou com um problema no *while*. A condição pro *while* terminar seria quando passasse por 20 números pares e 20 números ímpares, mas quando ele atinge a primeira condição (`contImpar == 20`, ou seja, chega no 39), ele para de repetir. Onde está o erro? Segue o trecho do código e o enunciado:

> Crie um algoritmo que some os primeiros 20 números inteiros impares e
>   imprima a soma destes. Mostre também o produto dos primeiros 10
>   números pares.

```
int contPar=0, contImpar=0, somaPar=0, somaImpar=0, aux=1;

while( (contImpar<20) && (contPar<20) ) {
    printf("%d: ", aux);
    if(aux % 2 == 0) {
        contPar++;
        printf("%d + %d = ", somaPar, aux);
        somaPar += aux;
        printf("%d   qtd par: %d\n", somaPar, contPar);
    } else {
        contImpar++;
        printf("%d + %d = ", somaImpar, aux);
        somaImpar += aux;
        printf("%d   qtd impar: %d\n", somaImpar, contImpar);
    }
    aux++;
}
```

Comment: Sua interpretação do exercício está errada. Tem algo que indique que tem que usar apenas um `while`? É uma lógica complicada a toa.

Comment: troque && por ||

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Sobre condição de parada, `while`, semântica da linguagem e o título da pergunta

Como o [@Maniero falou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238491/d%c3%bavida-no-while-com-duas-condi%c3%a7%c3%b5es#comment488237_238491), o erro está na sua interpretação e em como expressar ela na linguagem de programação.

Em [c](/questions/tagged/c), expressamos condição de continuidade, não de parada. Então, se a condição de parada é:

```
contImpar >= 20 && contPar >= 20
```

se negarmos ela teremos a condição de continuidade:

```
!(contImpar >= 20 && contPar >= 20)
```

Aplicando [De Morgan](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoremas_de_De_Morgan?wprov=sfti1):

```
!(contImpar >= 20) || !(contPar >= 30)
```

Sabendo que "menor-que" é o complemento de "maior-igual":

```
contImpar < 20 || contPar < 20
```

Conforme o comentário do [@Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238491/d%c3%bavida-no-while-com-duas-condi%c3%a7%c3%b5es#comment488241_238491).

Portanto, para fazer a mágica,

```
while (contImpar < 20 || contPar < 20)
```

## Sobre o problema contido na questão e busca dos primeiros números

> (Créditos ao [@Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/Maniero) por notar a falta dessa explicação).

Primeiramente, sobre o texto da questão:

> Crie um algoritmo que some os primeiros 20 números inteiros impares e imprima a soma destes. Mostre também o produto dos primeiros 10 números pares.

Em nenhum momento é especificado qual tipo de iteração será usada. Também não fala que deve ser realizado em uma única iteração. Nem que a iteração deva ser feita de maneira incremental. (Na verdade, nem precisa de iteração, só verificar a [resposta do @AndersonCarlosWoss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/239238/64969) para a fórmula do somatório).

Vamos resolver essa questão de diversas maneiras? Mas, antes, vamos analisar algumas propriedades de somatórios e produtórios.

> ### Sobre o número 0 e sua paridade
>
> O número 0 é um número par, pois `0 % 2 == 0`. Assim, considerando o número dos naturais a partir do `0`, ele seria o primeiro número par. Porém, como ele é o elemento absorvente da multiplicação, o resultado de qualquer produtório que o inclua seria trivialmente 0.
>
> Como isso é entediante, o resultado não deve ser trivialmente 0.
>
> (Créditos ao [@AndersonCarlosWoss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) por notar a falta dessa explicação).

### Somatórios e produtórios

Um somatório é uma soma sobre um conjunto de itens. Isso pode ser definido de maneira recursiva:

```
somatório(lista):
  se lista.tamanho() == 0:
    retorne 0
  senão:
    último_elemento = lista.cauda()
    lista.remove_cauda()
    retorne somatório(lista) + último_elemento
```

Note que o somatório de um conjunto vazio é 0. Isso é útil porque zero é o elemento neutro da soma. Foi necessário criar esse caso para que a recursão chegue ao fim.

Porém, isso pode ser feito de maneira iterativa, não necessita ser feito recursivamente. Para tratar isso de maneira iterativa, precisamos dar um jeito de acumular o valor da soma, como se fosse a recursão.

Antes, vamos tentar expressar matematicamente a chamada para `somatório({a, b, c, d})`, abrindo a recursão conforme necessário:

```
somatório({a, b, c, d}) =
somatório({a, b, c}) + d =
(somatório({a, b}) + c) + d =
((somatório({a}) + b) + c) + d =
(((somatório({}) + a) + b) + c) + d =
((((0) + a) + b) + c) + d
```

Note como começamos do 0, então acumulamos com o primeiro elemento, então o segundo, até o último elemento. Isso poderia ser descrito algoritmicamente da seguinte maneira:

```
somatório(lista):
  acc = 0
  para i = 0; i < lista.tamanho(); i++:
    acc += lista.elemento(i)
  retorne acc
```

Para o produtório, basta mudar a operação e o elemento neutro. No caso, o elemento neutro é 1:

```
produtório(lista):
  se lista.tamanho() == 0:
    retorne 1
  senão:
    último_elemento = lista.cauda()
    lista.remove_cauda()
    retorne produtório(lista) * último_elemento
```

Fazendo o mesmo desmembramento da recursão que fizemos anteriormente, temos o seguinte:

```
produtório({a, b, c, d}) =
produtório({a, b, c}) * d =
(produtório({a, b}) * c) * d =
((produtório({a}) * b) * c) * d =
(((produtório({}) * a) * b) * c) * d =
((((1) * a) * b) * c) * d
```

De modo semelhante, podemos fazer a seguinte acumulação para o produtório:

```
produtório(lista):
  acc = 1
  para i = 0; i < lista.tamanho(); i++:
    acc *= lista.elemento(i)
  retorne acc
```

### Iteração separada, `for`, iterando sobre índice de multiplicidade

Para pegar os primeiros 20 números ímpares, devemos começar com o número `1`, e o seguinte será `1 (+2) = 3`, e o seguinte `1 (+2+2) = 5` etc. Se analisar, a fórmula do `x`-ésimo número ímpar é `ímpar(x) = 1 + 2*x`. Como queremos os primeiros 20 números ímpares, podemos fazer a seguinte iteração:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  int impar = 1 + 2*i;
  printf("%d-esimo numero impar: %d\n", i + 1, impar);
}
```

Os números pares seguem uma fórmula semelhante, porém começa com `2`. Portanto, `par(x) = 2 + 2*x`. Portanto, os 10 primeiros números pares seria assim:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  int par = 2 + 2*i;
  printf("%d-esimo numero par: %d\n", i + 1, par);
}
```

Portanto, para fazer o somatório dos 20 primeiros números ímpares e o produtório dos primeiros 10 números pares:

```
int i;
int acc_soma = 0;
int acc_produto = 1;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  acc_soma += 1 + 2*i;
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  acc_produto *= 2 + 2*i;
}
printf("soma dos primeiros 20 impares: %d\n", acc_soma);
printf("produto dos primeiros 10 pares: %d\n", acc_produto);
```

### Iteração separada, `for`, iterando sobre o conjunto de números

A opção anterior é a mais óbvia para mim. Porém, eu posso fazer a iteração de maneira distinta. No lugar de iterar sobre o índice para só depois calcular o número, posso iterar diretamente sobre os números.

Assim, os primeiros 20 ímpares seria iterado assim:

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i < 1 + 20*2; i += 2) {
  int impar = i;
  printf("novo impar: %d\n", impar);
}
```

Para os pares:

```
int i;
for (i = 2; i < 2 + 10*2; i += 2) {
  int par = i;
  printf("novo par: %d\n", par);
}
```

Assim, a resposta seria desse jeito:

```
int i;
int acc_soma = 0;
int acc_produto = 1;
for (i = 1; i < 1 + 20*2; i += 2) {
  acc_soma += i;
}
for (i = 2; i < 2 + 10*2; i += 2) {
  acc_produto *= i;
}
printf("soma dos primeiros 20 impares: %d\n", acc_soma);
printf("produto dos primeiros 10 pares: %d\n", acc_produto);
```

### Iteração unificada, `while`, iterando incrementalmente

Bem, aqui vamos fazer usar a condição de parada que você colocou na pergunta. Como na linguagem não descrevemos condição de parada, mas de continuidade. Então, vamos usar o `while` descrito na primeira seção desta resposta:

```
while (contImpar < 20 || contPar < 20)
```

Para marcar que serão necessários apenas 10 números pares, vou usar o `while` da seguinte maneira:

```
while (contImpar < 20 || contPar < 10)
```

Para fazer a iteração completa, comecemos do número 1 e incrementemos. Basicamente, o mesmo que você usou, vou começar por ele. Só que vou usar `i` no lugar de `aux`. Também vou garantir que só irá para o acumulador se estiver dentro dos intervalos necessários (isto é, pares até o décimo, ímpares até o vigésimo).

```
int contPar = 0;
int contImpar = 0;
int produtoPar = 1;
int somaImpar = 0;
int i = 1;

while (contImpar < 20 || contPar < 10) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    if (contPar < 10) {
      contPar++;
      produtoPar *= i;
    }
  } else {
    if (contImpar < 20) {
      contImpar++;
      somaImpar += i;
    }
  }
  i++;
}
printf("soma dos 20 impares: %d\n", somaImpar);
printf("produto dos 10 pares: %d\n", produtoPar);
```

### Iteração unificada, `while (1)`, iterando incrementalmente, fim da iteração com `break`

Agora, mais para uma questão de academicismo. Não podemos colocar uma condição de parada no `while`, não tem como fugir disso. Em compensação, podemos colocar uma condicional com um `break`.

```
int contPar = 0;
int contImpar = 0;
int produtoPar = 1;
int somaImpar = 0;
int i = 1;

while (1) {
  if (contImpar >= 20 && contPar >= 10) {
    break;
  }
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    if (contPar < 10) {
      contPar++;
      produtoPar *= i;
    }
  } else {
    if (contImpar < 20) {
      contImpar++;
      somaImpar += i;
    }
  }
  i++;
}
printf("soma dos 20 impares: %d\n", somaImpar);
printf("produto dos 10 pares: %d\n", produtoPar);
```

Comment: Um jeito diferente de mostrar. Espero que o AP saiba De Morgan +1

Comment: @Amadeus você me deu a ideia de linkar a alguma referência. Não posso tomar por garantia que o AP saiba de tudo, né? Ou quem parar por aqui depois?

Comment: Ainda assim o código não faz o que o enunciado pede. Mas dei +1 porque resolve o que ele pergunta.

Comment: @bigown o AP tinha focado muita energia na parte do laço, então acabei por me focar apenas nisso; vou editar e por o resto que faça o desejado. Obrigado pelo feedback

Comment: @bigown, respondido

Comment: Talvez seja interessante colocar que o número zero é um número inteiro par, porém foi desconsiderado apenas por pedir o produto dos números e não fazer muito sentido, uma vez que sempre daria zero. O enunciado correto indicaria "números inteiros pares positivos".

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, certa dose de preguiça envolvia. Obrigado pelo _feedback_. Vou fazer isso já já

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, ajustado

Answer (score 1):

Aproveitando todo o empenho que o Jefferson teve em sua [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/238504/5878), proponho uma análise mais matemática do problema. Como comentado por ele, o próprio enunciado no problema não fala explicitamente que deve ser utilizado laços de repetição na solução. Essa geralmente é a primeira solução a ser considerada, mas não a única.

Sabemos que um número inteiro positivo ímpar pode ser representado como:

```
x = 2*i-1, para i = 1, 2, 3, ...
```

Assim, podemos dizer que se considerarmos N números ímpares, o último será `2*N-1` e a soma destes ficaria:

```
S = 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + ... + (2*N-1)
```

Analisando matematicamente a sequência, podemos perceber que esta soma nada mais é que a soma de elementos de uma progressão de números inteiros que crescem em uma razão igual a 2. Na matemática, chamamos-na de [progressão aritmética (PA)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress%C3%A3o_aritm%C3%A9tica) e a soma de elementos finitos de uma PA possui uma fórmula conhecida e fácil de demonstrar:

```
S = N*(a1+aN)/2
```

Sendo `N` o número de elementos, `a1` o primeiro elemento da sequência e `aN` o último. Substituindo os valores:

```
S = N*(1 + 2*N-1)/2
  = N²
```

Ou seja, a soma dos N primeiros números ímpares será igual ao quadrado de N. Em C, um programa simples para efetuar esse cálculo seria:

```
int main(void) {

  int N = 20;

  printf("A soma dos %d números ímpares é %d\n", N, N*N);

  return 0;

}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/OXzk84).

Porém, o cálculo do produto não é tão simplificado quanto a soma. Considerando apenas os números pares (e desconsiderando o zero por conveniência), o produto dos N primeiros números pares é dado por:

```
P = 2*4*6*...*(2*N)
```

Se analisarmos, por definição, todos os N valores são divisíveis por 2, então podemos colocá-los em evidência. Desta forma, o produto é simplificado para:

```
P = 2^N * (1*2*3*...*N)
  = 2^N * N!
```

Ou seja, para calcular o produto dos N primeiros números pares ainda se faz necessário calcular o valor de N!, que em C não seria possível (creio eu) fugir de um laço de repetição.

```
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

  int N = 10;
  int i;
  int fat = 1;

  for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) fat *= i;

  printf("O produto dos %d números pares é %f\n", N, pow(2, N)*fat);

  return 0;

}
```

> veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/wMlGsE).